# Swift 3 Firebase DB read Data Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have a strange issue.  I have a Firebase DB that is set up with some data.

I have a struct configured like so:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

struct newTracks {


let name: String!
let trackId: Int!
let postcode: String!
let trackType: String!
let locID: Int!
let lat: Double!
let lon: Double!
let phoneNumber: String!
let email: String!
let rating: Double!
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?



init(name: String, trackId: Int, postcode: String, trackType: String,   trackURL: String, locID: Int, lat: Double, lon: Double, phoneNumber: String, email: String, rating: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.trackId = trackId
    self.ref = nil
    self.postcode = postcode
    self.trackType = trackType
    self.locID = locID
    self.lat = lat
    self.lon = lon
    self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    self.email = email
    self.rating = rating

}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    print(snapshotValue)
    name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
    trackId = snapshotValue["id"]as! Int
    postcode = snapshotValue["postcode"]as! String
    trackType = snapshotValue["type"]as! String
    locID = snapshotValue["locID"]as! Int
    lat = snapshotValue["lat"]as! Double
    lon = snapshotValue["long"]as! Double
    phoneNumber = snapshotValue["phone"]as! String
    email = snapshotValue["email"]as! String
    rating = snapshotValue["rating"]as! Double
    ref = snapshot.ref

}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "name": name,
        "trackId": trackId,
        "postcode": postcode,
        "trackType": trackType,
        "locID": locID,
        "lat": lat,
        "lon": lon,
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
        "email": email,
        "rating": rating
            ]
}

}
```

This is referenced on my viewcontroller with the follwoing code:

```
func getTrackData() {

    let result = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "tracks")
    result.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var newItems: [newTracks] = []
        print(newItems)

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let trackDetails = newTracks(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(trackDetails)
          }
        print(newItems)

        self.items = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
}
```

Currently i am getting "Unexpectedly found NIL while  unwrapping an optional value"  I have found why I am getting that, and it is because from the first block of code, the following line runs

```
print(snapshotValue)
```

the following results are produce:

"["name": J4M54, "email": here@there.com, "postcode": TF11 1XX, "rating": 1, "type": Soil, "lat": 52.679089, "spares": No, "jetwash": No, "toilets": No, "long": -2.398844, "id": 8, "phone": 01234 123456, "locID": 353823, "club": Practice Track]

["rating": 4]"

this is just a snippet of the results, as there are many that come out.  The issue is with the very last part of the result

["rating": 4]"

This doesnt exist in my DB.  It is a phantom result.

I have tried recreating my DB Data using a backup of my JSON, and this result just doesnt exist anywhere in the data, so I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why cant you just put a failable initializer and place an nil check ?

Comment: Im mostly concerned about where that phantom data is being called from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I had DB persistance on in my AppDelegate, and it had stored the value after some work I was doing to write to the DB

Turned persistance off and its now fine